# c++ validate input value before add it to array

Tags: c++, arrays, validation

My target is to validate input value before add it into array. Current code used:

```
int main()
{
    int temp;
    int arr[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        // validate here
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and my validation method:

```
int validateInput(string prompt)
{
    int val;
    while (true)
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.sync();
        cout << prompt;
        cin >> val;
        if (cin.good() && val >= -50 && val <= 50)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
            cin.clear();
        cout << "Invalid input! number must be between -50 and 50" << endl;
    }
    return val;
}
```

How is that possible?

Comment: How is *what* possible?

Comment: You have a function that reads some input and "validates" it, what is the problem with it?

Comment: With C++, you could build something that enables you to write `cin >> Foo(arr[i], -50, 50)`. Google "overloading istream >>". Alas, the boring simple way is probably more practical.

Comment: Prefer to use `std::vector`.  Arrays have the possibility of buffer overflow, and are difficult to pass to functions (compared to vectors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
cin >> temp;
```

with

```
arr[i] = validateInput("some str");
```

Comment: There's no `temp` in the question.  Are you sure this is an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Your `validateInput` should just deal with validation: it should answer **"is `x` valid or not valid?"**

```
bool validateInput(int x)
{
    return val >= -50 && val <= 50;
}
```

When reading from *stdin*, use `validateInput` and branch accordingly:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int temp;
    cin >> temp;

    if(cin.good() && validateInput(temp))
    {
        arr[i] = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid input! number must be between -50 and 50" << endl;
        // handle invalid input
    }
}
```

---

If you want to further abstract the idea of "only reading valid numbers from `std::cin`", you can use an *higher-order function*:

```
template <typename TFValid, typename TFInvalid, typename TFInvalidIO>
decltype(auto) processInput(TFValid&& f_valid, TFInvalid&& f_invalid, TFInvalidIO&& f_invalid_io)
{
     int temp;
     cin >> temp;

     if(!cin.good()) 
     {
         // Invalid IO.
         return std::forward<TFInvalidIO>(f_invalid_io)();
     }

     if(validateInput(temp))
     {
         // Valid IO and datum.
         return std::forward<TFValid>(f_valid)(temp);
     }

     // Valid IO, but invalid datum.
     return std::forward<TFInvalid>(f_invalid)(temp);
}
```

Usage:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    processInput([&](int x){ arr[i] = x; },
                 [](int x){ cout << x << " is invalid"; },
                 []{ cout << "Error reading from cin"; });
}
```

If you want more genericity you can also pass `validateInput` and the type of input as an additional parameters.

Comment: You might want to add the `cin >> temp` as part of the condition in the `if` statement.

Comment: No no, I have validation method, which I want to combine in main

Comment: In your answer if input is not valid, it will not prompt again. In my method it prompts till valid

Comment: You most likely want `cin.good() && validateInput(temp)`, i.e. `&&` instead of logical bit-and `&`. For `bool` the only difference will be in that `&&` does short-cicuit evaluation, but for non-bools, `&` is very different from `&&`.

Comment: @vsoftco: that was a typo :)

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Yes I knew :) I wrote the rest of the comment more for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Vittorio's answer above is spot on. For completeness, if you want exactly 5 elements:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool validateInput(int inValue)
{
  return inValue >= -50 && inValue <= 50;
}

int main()
{
  int _arr[5];
  int _currentIdx = 0;
  int _tmp;
  while (_currentIdx < 5)
  {
    cin >> _tmp;
    if (validateInput(_tmp))
    {
      _arr[_currentIdx] = _tmp;
      _currentIdx++;
    }
    else
    {
      cout << "Invalid input! number must be between -50 and 50" << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In your answer if input is not valid, it will not prompt again. In my method it prompts till valid

Comment: @TeodorKolev How so? If input is invalid `_currentIdx` is not increased and it will prompt again for the given array index.